# Updating multiple page elements without refreshing the page using PHP & jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a PHP page that uses jQuery to let a user update a particular item without needing to refresh the page.  It is an availability update where they can change their availability for an event to Yes, No, or Maybe.  Each time they click on the link the appropriate jQuery function is called to send data to a separate PHP file (update_avail.php) and the appropriate data is returned.

```
<a href="javascript(void);" onClick="updateAvail(params);">Yes</a>
```

Then when clicked the params are sent to a PHP file which returns back:

```
<a href="javascript(void);" onClick="updateAvail(params);">No</a>
```

Then, if clicked again the PHP will return:

```
<a href="javascript(void);" onClick="updateAvail(params);">Maybe</a>
```

It all works fine and I'm loving it.

BUT--

I also have a total count at the bottom of the page that is PHP code to count the total number of users that have selected Yes as their availability by simply using:

```
<?php count($event1_accepted); ?>
```

How can I make it so that if a user changes their availability it will also update the count without needing to refresh the page?

My thoughts so far are:

```
$var = 1;
while ($var > 0) {
    count($day1_accepted);
    $var = 0;
    exit;
}
```

Then add a line to my 'update_avail.php' (which gets sent data from the jQuery function) to make $var = 1

Any help would be great.  I would like to stress that my main strength is PHP, not jQuery, so a PHP solution would be preferred, but if necessary I can tackle some simple jQuery.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In the response from update_avail.php return a JSON object with both your replacement html and your new counter value.

Or to keep it simple, if they click "yes" incriment the counter, if they click No or maybe and their previous action wasn't No or Maybe decrease the counter.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your users are logged into the system I'd recommend having a status field in the user table, perhaps as an enum with "offline", "available", "busy", "unavailable" or something similar and use the query the number of available users whilst updating the users status.

If you were to do this you'd need to include in extend your methods containing session)start() and session_destroy() to change the availability of the user to available / offline respectively

Answer (score -1):

The best way is the one suggested by Scuzzy with some improvements.

In your php, get the count from the database and return a JSON object like:

```
{ count: 123, html: '<a href="javascript(void);" onClick="updateAvail(params);">Yes</a>' }
```

In your page, in the ajax response you get the values and update the elements:

```
...
success: function(data) {
    $("#linkPlaceholder").html(data.html);
    $("#countPlaceholder").html(data.count);
}
...
```

Comment: use of innerHTML is **never** the solution !

Comment: Can you explain to bare mortals why this is so bad?